# excel nuget package for .net core

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I need some library for .net core to help me create an excel file (no matter the exact file extension).

I tried to use the `MICROSOFT.OFFICE.INTEROP.EXCEL.DLL` (windows dll), I searched for it in the nuget gallery, I tried to find other package with core support, but I didnt managed to find one.

Is there a library witch can help me?

Comment: If you need a simple excel file, you can create a `.csv` file. Just write lines in the format: "col1;col2;col3;....;coln" into a file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the think is that I need to inject formulas in some of the fields and I think that this is possible with .csv. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Didn't you find the `microsoft.office.interop.excel` package or didn't it work?

Comment: Even if you do find a NuGet package, [you are not supposed to use the office interop with ASP.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757), it is not supported and breaks easily. Look in to non-automation libraries that can manipulate excel files. (for example [the Open XML SDK for office](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXMLSDK-MOT/))

Comment: @FabricioKoch it didn't work because of the version, I don't remember the exact error.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I will take your advice, I already made a research about the Open XML SDK and I found it useful, easy and clean.

Comment: @n_ananiev Was Open XML SDK able to create an xls file?

Answer (score 5):

You should try EPPlus.Core:

Here is how to read an Excel using that library (tried myself [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1217036/Console-Logging-and-Reading-Excel-Files-with-NET-C)):

```
var filePath = @"D:/test.xlsx";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{       
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
    int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

    var rawText = string.Empty;
    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= ColCount; col++)
        {   
            // This is just for demo purposes
            rawText += worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t";    
        }
        rawText+="\r\n";
    }
    _logger.LogInformation(rawText);
}
```

And at the offictial page I've found a complete example in ASP.Net Core here: https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core/tree/master/src/EPPlus.Core.SampleWebApp

Juan

Comment: This package is no more Open source.

Comment: EPPlus Core is open source and APPlus 5 too, don't confuse open software with free software. https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html#:~:text=Nearly%20all%20open%20source%20software,version%20and%20using%20it%20privately.

Comment: Thx Juan, can you point me this open source version exactly https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core  (this seems to be dead)

Comment: "EPPlus has from this new major version changed license from LGPL to Polyform Noncommercial 1.0.0.

With the new license EPPlus is still free to use in some cases, but will require a commercial license to be used in a commercial business."

Comment: Ok this alternative is MIT licensed https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: @EinoMäkitalo - good alternative for me - IMHO should be posted as a new answer!